# disable radio button group when checkbox is checked jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

hi to you all i got my code here which i think is right and which is supposed to work fine but it doesn't.i have a radio button group and a checkbox.each of the radio button has a value which will be used as an amount and the checkbox is there only to enable the textbox that will allow the users to enter the amount they want.i made it possible to enable the textbox by checking if it has been checked first.i want to disable the radio group while the checkbox is enabled.
here is a screenshot of what my page actually looks like

[image]

here is my html

```
     <label class="radio-inline" style="margin-left:15%;" >
                            <input type="radio" id="amount_suggest_1" name="montantdon" value="50 000" onFocus="this.blur()"  >
                         50 000</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" id="amount_suggest_2" name="montantdon" value="25 000" onfocus="this.blur()" >25 000</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" id="amount_suggest_3" name="montantdon" value="10000" onfocus="this.blur()" >10 000</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" id="amount_suggest_4" name="montantdon" value="5000" onfocus="this.blur()" >5000</label>
    <label class="radio-inline lastradio"><input type="radio" id="amount_suggest_5" name="montantdon" value="1000" onfocus="this.blur()"  checked>1 000</label>
```

```
                        <div class="row" style="padding-left:20px;">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-5" style="width:200px;width:200px;margin:auto;margin-top:2%;">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-amount" >
                                <label class=""><input type="checkbox" name="autresdon" id="autresdon" />&nbsp;Autres</label>
                                    <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;"><input type="text" style="width:50px;" name="amountentered" id="amountentered" disabled /></div>
                                    <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
                                  <div class="input-group-btn" style="position:relative;">
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle currency-current" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="currency" id="currency">EUR-€</span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
```

and here is my jquery code

```
          $('#autresdon').click(function(){//on click the checkbox
      if($('#autresdon').is(':checked'))
                {
                $('#amountentered').prop("disabled",false);//enables textbox
                }
                else
                {
                $('#amountentered').prop("disabled",true);//on unset checkbox disable textbox
                }
      });

      //disabling radio group by using their class as selector
             $('.montantdon ').click(function(){
             if($('#autresdon').is(':checked'))
             {
                $('#autresdon').prop("checked",false);
                }
      });
```

i dont want both data(value of the radios and amount entered manually) to be posted.how can i solve this issue? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I'd suggest:

```
// binds the change-handler:
$('#autresdon').change(function(){
    // sets the 'disabled' property to false (if the 'this' is checked, true if not):
    $('.radio-inline').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
// triggers the change event (so the disabled property is set on page-load:
}).change();
```

Incidentally, with JavaScript (and *especially* in jQuery, in which it becomes entirely unnecessary) *stay away* from in-line/obtrusive JavaScript. using `onFocus`/`onfocus`, `onchange`, `onclick` etc makes for a maintenance nightmare and creates some terribly (and, again, unnecessarily) *untidy* HTML.

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: I like this approach. No `if` required.